# I want two controls to ovelap that is Select and Input controls. Toggling the controls

Tags: html, css, angularjs-directive

My requirement is In angular I want to `OnFocus` replace `<input>` with `<select>` And on `outFocus` i want to again display `<input>` .

I want to make either of these two visible.

And I want both on the same position to overlap each other.